# Is there any way to call a function defined inside another function?

Tags: javascript

Without changing the structure of my code listed below.  Is there anyway to call the **onCancel()** function from outside the **pushy()** function?  Something along the lines of

```
pushy().onCancel();
```

I have the following code

```
function pushy(argument1,argument2)
    {

              var onSuccess = function(e) {     
                   alert('1');
              };

              var onCancel = function(e) {      
                   alert('2');
              };     

  }
```

So basically from outside of these functions I would like to **alert 2**

Comment: No, it's not possible. There's no way to access variables that are inside the scope of another function. This is the normal way to create the equivalent of private members in Javascript.

Comment: `return {onCancel:onCancel}`

Comment: @guest271314 He said he can't change the function.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it is necessary to change the function. OP asks how to change the function. Else functionality would be available at existing function, or OP asks an impossible Question; perform a different procedure without changing what current procedure is capable of.

Comment: No, he didn't ask how to change the function. He said "Without changing the structure of my code listed below."

Comment: That's why my first comment says "it's not possible".

Comment: @Barmar Yes,  concur. Then Question is relegated to an impossibility. Else OP would be able to perform the task presently.

Comment: That's right. He asked if it's possible, I told him no, and closed it as a duplicate of another question that says the same thing.

Comment: Without changing? It's one method... and it's crazy. Don't do that if you don't know how dangerous it is. You can get ``pushy.toString()``, then create your own functions with ``eval`` and have fun. But that's just crazy solution. Working, but crazy.

Comment: No - it IS possible. In crazy way, but it is possible!

Comment: @Sylogista That approach would create a different function, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes. I know what that mean – that's not exactly what OP's talking about, but that's closest answer in my opinion.